# Different definitions of the transfer map are equivalent

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology

I have been reading Brown's book on Cohomology of groups and in the section about the transfer map he talks about the different definitions that one can give to it, that is

$(1)$For any $G$-module $M$ and any $H\subset G$ we have a canonical surjection of $g$-modules $\mathbb{Z}[G]\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[H]}M \rightarrow M $ and a canonical injection $M \rightarrow Hom_{\mathbb{Z}[H]}(\mathbb{Z}[G],M)$. If we assume now that $[G:H]<\infty$, then $\mathbb{Z}[G]\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[H]}M \cong Hom_{\mathbb{Z}[H]}(\mathbb{Z}[G],M)$. Consequently we can apply $H^*(G,-)$ and $H_*(G,-)$ and shapiro's-lemma to the previous maps to obtain transfer maps going on the other direction$cor_H^G : H^*(H,M)\rightarrow H^*(G,M)$, $res_H^G : H_*(G,M) \rightarrow H_*(H,M)$,or simply $tr_H^G$ if it is clear from context wheter we are talking about $H^*$ or $H_*$.

$(2)$For any $H\subset G$ we can regard both $H_*(G,-)$ and $H_*(H,-)$ as homological functors on the category of $G-$modules, and both are effaceable in positive dimensions, since modules that are $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ projective are also $\mathbb{Z}[H]$ projective. Assuming now that $[G:H]<\infty $ we define $tr : M_G \rightarrow M_H$ by $tr(\bar m)=\sum_{g\in H/G}\overline{\overline{ gm}}$, where $\overline{m}$(resp. $\overline{\overline{m}}$) denotes the image of $m$ in $M_G$ (resp. $M_H$), notice that this sum makes sense because $\overline{\overline{gm}}$ depends only on the class of $g \in G/H$, we define $res:H_*(G,-)\rightarrow H_*(H,-)$ to be the unique extension of $tr$ to a map of homological funtors.To see that this agrees with the previous definition we need to verify that the latter is compapatible with $\partial$ and equals $tr$ in dimension zero.Similarly, we can define $cor:H^*(H,-) \rightarrow H^*(G,-)$ as the unique map of cohomolgical functors wich in dimension zero is the map $tr: M^H \rightarrow M^G $ defined by $tr(m)=\sum_{g\in G/H}gm$, to verify co-effaceability of $H^*(H,-)$ on the category of $G$-modules we note that a co-induced $G$-module is also co-induced as an $H$-module.

Question : Now I wanted to see that these definitions are in fact equivalent, he talks about how one could this, now my idea to check this by what he said would be to actually to find the chain map that would agree with the homomorphisms of $(1)$ and compute its effect on  dimension $0$, but to check that this agrees with $\partial$ is there an easier less computational way that having to say take the bar resolution find out what these maps really are in all dimensions and see that they actually work well with $\partial$? It just seems to be a little overkill.

New edit : Also I am confused with this last part shouldnt we be showing that $tr : H_0(G,M) \rightarrow H_0(H,M)$ is actually a natural transformation , because we need that this map is a natural transformation so that we can extend to the rest of natural transformations and get the rest of the natural transformations and then the map between the functors? Also I have another idea for showing that this map agrees with $\partial$ that is basically using the naturality of the connecting homomorphism with respect to maps of short exact sequences.

What I have already tried to see that they were the same in dimension $0$ was to zero what were the map on the chain levels but still I havent gotten the right result, when if we take $F$ a resolution over $g$, we have $F\otimes M \rightarrow F\otimes Coind_H^G M \rightarrow F\otimes Ind_H^G M \rightarrow F\otimes M$ where the last one if the isomorphism given by shapiro's Lemma.
So we will have that $\overline{m}\rightarrow 1\otimes m \rightarrow 1\otimes[x\rightarrow xm]\rightarrow 1\otimes (\sum_{g\in G/H}g\otimes g^{-1}m) \rightarrow \sum_{g\in G/H}1\otimes m \rightarrow \sum_{g\in G/H} \overline{\overline{m}}$ so yeah I dont get the right result, altough there might be a mistake in one of these steps cause I might have confused the $G$-action and the $H-$action in the modules, and the summand is supposed to be in the classes $Hg$ and not $gH$ so that might be another mistake that might help figure out what's wrong, I guess my real difficulty is figuring out what I did wrong in this last part.

Any help or tips are aprecciated, Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Have you tried using the proof of Shapiro's lemma ?

Comment: I have not, still dont quite see how it would help but I will think about it, do you refer to the part that he leaves as an exercise? I guess it could help with seeing dimension zero but I am not sure about agreeing with $\partial$.